# Deploys stuck in Production uploading Netlify

Tags: netlify

Sorry this may seem like a stupid question, I'm quite new to the Netlify platform but I am using the drag and drop feature to update my static website. After dragging and dropping the Deploys page simply has a Production uploading and there is nothing in the deploy log.

Is there a hard limit on what I am uploading (I haven't uploaded anything over 2GB) or do I have to upload via the Command Line Interface?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

disclaimer: I work for Netlify.

Drag and drop deploys to Netlify are the least reliable type.  They rely on a bunch of things working perfectly:

1. your computer - should have quite a bit of memory since the entire site needs to fit in memory potentially twice (if you use a zipfile)
2. your network connection - needs to be ROCK SOLID.  if the connection drops during deployment, it is unlikely to resume
3. your site size.  2GB isn't "a limit" but I wouldn't expect a drag and drop deploy of over 100MByte to work well on a regular basis.

[CLI](https://www.netlify.com/docs/cli) or [Git-backed](https://www.netlify.com/docs/continuous-deployment/) deployments are far more reliable, plus they give us some opportunity to debug what went wrong which drag and drop deploys do not (no logging on our side, no debug logs possible on your side).

If the deployment hung in uploading status for more than a couple of minutes, it will never complete and you should try again (preferably via the CLI :)).

In general questions like these are probably better handled in [Netlify's helpdesk](https://www.netlify.com/support).  In this case I would have given you the same answer there.

Comment: Old topic, but I just ran into this, myself.  The netlify-cli utility is definitely the solution.  You have to clear a few hurdles to use it, but once I got past that, the upload was practically instantaneous for my (small-ish) site.